# Virtual Hosts in Apache Web Server and Apache Tomcat Environment

Tags: apache, tomcat, liferay, alfresco, odoo

I have a number of web applications which come with their bundled Apache Tomcat Server. When this tomcat server runs they give me options to access the application using something like http://IPAddress:8080/abcdef/

Now on test servers I can always point a domain name to the server and then use http://domain:8080/abcdef to access the web application but in order to set it up on a domain (without port number) only I have been suggested that I should use either mod_proxy or mod_jk for apache which improves the performance of the application server.

Now the big question is that why should I use mod_proxy or mod_jk. What benefits does it give me and then how should I configure it because it is bundled tomcat am I going to hack in the core of the application? Would that configuration be erased/overwritten during upgrade process?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess all your questions are already answered here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/proxy-howto.html.

**EDIT:** Furthermore, you get some performance and security benefits when using a reverse proxy:

1. you only have a *dumb* web server in your DMZ which protects your application. It also enables you to open a reduced number of ports between your DMZ and your internal hosting zone.
2. the web server can serve static content reducing load on your app server.
3. the web server can also terminate TLS (SSL), again removing load from your app server:

`CLIENT ---<https>--- APACHE ---<http>--- TOMCAT`